# How replace keys of a dictionary with keys of another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries dict1 and dict2. I want to replace the keys of dict1 with keys of dict2.
dict1.keys() is as follows:

```
dict_keys(['8014.png54523', '7595.png37735', '6659.png50805', '8058.png26143','05324.png31372'])
```

dict2.keys() is as follows:

```
dict_keys(['8014.png671302', '7595.png567733', '6659.png681968', '8058.png442154', '05324.png530138'])
```

I want dict2.keys() as dict1.keys. Can anyone help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you going to assign the values? What is the logic behind the substitution?

Comment: I have already assigned the values. The logic is to compare the key of dict1 with dict2, if it is not equal, subsititute dict2.keys with dict1.keys.

Comment: If not equal to what? What will be the new for '8014.png54523`, for instance?

Comment: Explain replacement algorithm else : dict(zip(d2.keys(),d1.values()))

Comment: You can't just `zip` keys and values, dictionary is designed unordered. So, first you should have ordered dictionary. You should have index. And, if you have index, it seems you should have a table with 3 columns: index, dict_key, dict_value.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
new_dict = {k2:dict1[k1] for k1, k2 in zip(dict1.keys(), dict2.keys())}
```

**Test**

*Keys & dummy values*

```
keys1 = ['8014.png54523', '7595.png37735', '6659.png50805', '8058.png26143','05324.png31372']
vals1 = list(range(len(keys1)))
keys2 = ['8014.png671302', '7595.png567733', '6659.png681968', '8058.png442154', '05324.png530138']
vals2 = list(range(len(keys1)))
```

*Dictionaries*

```
dict1 = dict(zip(keys1, vals1))
dict2 = dict(zip(keys2, vals2))
```

*New Dictionary*

```
# Have each k1, v1 in dict1
# and       k2, v2 from dict2
# new dict uses k2:v1
# where v1 = dict1[k1]
new_dict = {k2:dict1[k1] for k1, k2 in zip(dict1.keys(), dict2.keys())}

print(new_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{'8014.png671302': 0, '7595.png567733': 1, '6659.png681968': 2, '8058.png442154': 3, '05324.png530138': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
new_dict1 = {new_key: dict1[old_key] for old_key, new_key in zip(dict1.keys(), dict2.keys())}
```